# Returning static const reference to object from functions

Tags: c++, oop

In Effective C++ (Item 18: Make interfaces easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly), I saw a code sample similar to the following:

```
class Month
{
public:
    static Month Jan()
    {
        return Month(1);
    }

    static Month Feb()
    {
        return Month(2);
    }

    //...

    static Month Dec()
    {
        return Month(12);
    }

private:
    explicit Month(int nMonth)
        : m_nMonth(nMonth)
    {
    }

private:
    int m_nMonth;
};

Date date(Month::Mar(), Day(30), Year(1995));
```

Are there any drawbacks of changing the functions so that they return static const reference to Month?

```
class Month
{
public:
    static const Month& Jan()
    {
        static Month month(1);
        return month;
    }

    static const Month& Feb()
    {
        static Month month(2);
        return month;
    }

    //...

    static const Month& Dec()
    {
        static Month month(12);
        return month;
    }

private:
    explicit Month(int nMonth)
        : m_nMonth(nMonth)
    {
    }

private:
    int m_nMonth;
};
```

I thought the second version is a bit more efficient than the first one.

Comment: The _primary_ thing is that your code isn't threadsafe in C++03, only conforming C++11 compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Reason 1: It's not better.**

Returning by value incurs the cost of copying the entire object.

Returning by reference incurs the cost of copying what's effectively a pointer, plus the cost of dereferencing that pointer.

Since `Month` is the size of an `int`:

- Copying a reference is no faster than copying a `Month`
- Dereferencing would be incurred every time that reference is accessed.

So in general, returning by const reference is an optimization chosen to prevent what would be a costly copy.

**Reason 2: `static` makes it worse**

Unlike C, C++ promises that a static variable in a function will be constructed at the time of the function's first call.

In practice this means that every call to the function must begin with some unseen logic to determine if it's the first call.

See also Vaughn Cato's answer

See also ildjam's comment

Comment: So returning a reference to an object is more efficient only when size of object is greater than primitive data types?

Comment: What if the Month class had other member variables in it?

Comment: @jpen: There's no definitive rule, but as the object grows it becomes more likely that returning a reference would be more efficient.

Comment: what if each static function returned a private static class member instead? or each month was a public static member?

Comment: @d7samurai You seem to have a good reason to click the "Ask Question" button at the top of this page.  :)

Comment: @DrewDormann I was just suggesting what actually _might_ be a more efficient solution.. :)

Comment: What is your basis for assuming a reference requires a pointer? That seems incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Some compilers won't inline methods that contain static local variables, and inlining is the most important performance optimization here.

Comment: "inlining is the most important performance optimization here." Is it? I am not disagreeing I really do not know. Any more information on this?

Comment: @marsh: That is based on my experience.  Because the individual month functions are essentially returning a constant, the compiler has a lot of opportunity to take advantage of inlining.  For example, if you are doing a date calculation, it could calculate the result at compile time instead of run time.

Comment: I did not think about calculating the result at compile time. Good thought.

Comment: @marsh see this incredible and extensive article «How to optimize C and C++ code in 2018» at https://medium.com/@aka.rider/how-to-optimize-c-and-c-code-in-2018-bd4f90a72c2b